# How to call a function from one file into another in javascript using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have created two files one is a index.js file and another is a image.js file.The data is getting stored in a json file.

`index.js`:

```
const image=require('./image');
const request=require('request');
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const fs = require("fs");
const url = "https://www.google.com";
axios.get(url).then((res) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
const pageTitle = $("title").text();

const imageFile=image.imageNames();
console.log(imageFile)
const contentJSON = {
    title: pageTitle.trim(),
    url:url.trim(),
    listImages:listImages
  };
const artFinal = JSON.stringify(contentJSON);
  const filename = pageTitle.slice(0, 9).trim() + ".json";
  fs.writeFileSync(filename, artFinal);
});
```

`image.js`:

```
const request=require('request');
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const url = "https://www.google.com";
axios.get(url).then((res) => {
 const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
function  imageNames(){
    var listImages=[];
    $('*').find('img').each(function (index, element) {
      var img={
        name: $(element).attr('href'),
        dom_data:$(element).attr(''),
      };
      listImages.push(img)
    });
}
module.exports={imageNames};
});
```

I tried calling the function imageNames() from image.js file to index.js file.It is giving me an error message saying it is not a function.I am not understanding why i am getting this error .Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't export from the module asynchronously.

`const image=require('./image');` reads the value of `module.exports` **before** `module.exports={imageNames};` assigns a new value to it.

You could export the return value of `axios.get().then()` (which would be a promise) and change `module.exports={imageNames};` to `return imageNames` so that promise resolves to the function you want.

It would probably be better to run `imageNames` and have the promise resolve as the resulting array though.